# Why do unused overloads require a project reference?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for an explanation as to why unused constructor overloads that contain an unreferenced class would create a compile time error when using the other constructors in that class will build and run correctly.

Here's some example code that demonstrates the issue.

```
// Console Project - references CL1 but not CL2
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var rc1 = new ReferencedClass(); // compiles and runs
    var rc2 = new ReferencedClass(1); // wont compile. Needs CL2 reference
    var rc3 = new ReferencedClass(0, ""); // compiles and runs
}

// Class Library 1 (CL1) - references CL2
public class ReferencedClass
{
    private UnreferencedClass _unreferencedClass;
    public ReferencedClass()
    {
        _unreferencedClass = new UnreferencedClass();
    }

    public ReferencedClass(Int32 id)
    {
        _unreferencedClass = new UnreferencedClass();           
    }

    public ReferencedClass(UnreferencedClass uf)
    {
        _unreferencedClass = uf;
    }

    public ReferencedClass(Int32 id, String name)
    {
        _unreferencedClass = new UnreferencedClass();
    }
}

// Class Library 2 (CL2)
public class UnreferencedClass {}
```

In all cases, the constructor with the unreferenced class isn't used so why does the build fail on the `Int32` overloaded constructor?

Comment: The only reason you would not need a reference a build time is if you are not even referencing the type in the project. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it will be hard for most people to even duplicate your experience, never mind tell you why it happens. But the most likely cause I can think of is that you've got another `UnitOfWork` type running around in project A, but without the single-parameter constructor.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the incomplete code. It turns out I was hiding the problem from you all. I left out the third constructor in `UnitOfWork` which took an `Entities` parameter. I guess the parameterless version ran fine because it didn't have to look through the 1 parameter overloads.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to proceed with this question. I can edit the question, delete it, accept the 1 answer below and move on, or just leave things alone and let a mod handle it. Advice?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the primary question you need to ask yourself is: is there a way to edit the question and/or answer so that the combination will be _useful_ to a future reader. To me, this means considering such question as "are the symptoms likely to match those of someone else's well enough that they can find this question with a search?", and "is the answer written in a way such that it would help such a person, assuming they do find the question." If you can edit to make it useful, then do so...otherwise, the question should probably be deleted (by you...no need to make a mod. do it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler needs the type during overload resolution.

See here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817276/error-cs0012-the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-issued-for-an-extension-method-that-is-not-used

Paraphrased answer from the connect link:

> In the course of ascribing meaning to the name "ReferencedClass" in
>   your program, the compiler follows its lookup rules to determine the
>   set of methods that it must examine. Both constructors taking one
>   argument are examined as part of overload resolution. In order to
>   determine which one makes sense for the call, the compiler must
>   understand all of the types in the constructors' signatures. If some
>   types are not found due to missing references, the compiler does not
>   simply discard the candidate but instead requires that the user supply
>   the missing references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code example is incomplete. As you quote it here, it does not reproduce the error.

It would reproduce if

- You had another class UnitOfWork around somewhere, which also had a Context property, but of a different type, and
- You were using UnitOfWork.Context in ProjectA.

Like so:

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class UnitOfWork
    {
        public UnitOfWork()
        {
        }
        public string Context { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in ProjectA, this would compile fine:

```
using SomeNamespace;

//...

public void MyFunc()
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    // ...
    var context = unitOfWork.Context;
    // ...
}
```

Even this would compile fine:

```
using ProjectB;

//...

public void MyFunc()
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(1);
    // ...
}
```

But this would need the extra reference:

```
using ProjectB;

//...

public void MyFunc()
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(1);
    // ...
    var context = unitOfWork.Context;
    // ...
}
```